# some time after me vs sometime after me

Tags: grammar

From [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/e/sometime-vs-sometimes-vs-some-time/)

> **Sometime** refers to an unspecified point in time.

> The two-word expression **some time** means a period of time or quite a while.

I meant to say I pressed the bell first and she pressed the bell after some time lapsed.

This is my sentence: *She pressed the bell **some time** after me*.

Grammarly has corrected it to: *She pressed the bell **sometime** after me*.

I'm not sure which is the correct version?

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer your version. Most examples with relative time seem to use "some time" - *some time ago*, *some time since*, etc. And in your case, I think you *do* mean a period of time. If it can be substituted with "a while", "some time" is appropriate;  if it can be preceded by "at", then "sometime" is the right choice. Which one do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

*She pressed the bell **sometime** after me* means that the time elapsed between your action and hers is unknown, or at least unspecified.

*She pressed the bell **some time** after me* can be understood to mean that the time lapsed between the actions was substantial. Here, and with that interpretation, *some time after* has the meaning *no small amount of time after*, or *quite some time after*.